# Node.js Passport failed to deserilize user

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

My node.js app has two passport local strategies. One for back office users and another for guests. Both strategies query two different tables for authenticating their respective users.

Below is the passport.js code

```
var isOfficeUser = false;

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    if(isOfficeUser == true){
        done(null, user.idSystemUser);
    } else {
        done(null, user.idGuests);
    }
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    var userQuery;

    if(isOfficeUser == true) {
        userQuery = 'SELECT idSystemUser, Name, Email, Phone, (select IsGuest from SystemProfiles where idSystemProfile = ProfileId) as GuestFlag FROM SystemUsers WHERE idSystemUser = ? ';
    } else {
        userQuery = 'SELECT idGuests, Name, Email, RoomId, GuestsCount, Phone, RoomNo, ' +
        '(select DATE_FORMAT(CheckInDT, \'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p\')) as CheckInDTString, ' +
        '(select DATE_FORMAT(CheckOutDT, \'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p\')) as CheckOutDTString, ' +
        '(select IsGuest from SystemProfiles where idSystemProfile = ProfileId) as GuestFlag ' +
        'FROM Guests WHERE idGuests = ? ';
    }

    connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if (err) {
            winston.log('debug', '------------------------------------ Error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        connection.query(userQuery,[id],function(err, rows){
            if(err) {
                winston.info('info', '----------------------- ERROR: ' + err);
            }
            done(err, rows[0]);
            connection.release();
        });
    });
});


//this stretegy is for guests
passport.use(
    'guest',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'room',
        passwordField : 'accesskey',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, room, accesskey, done) {
        isOfficeUser = false;
        connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            if(err) {
                winston.log('debug', '------------------------------------ Error: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            connection.query('SELECT idGuests, Name, Email, RoomId, RoomNo, GuestsCount, Phone FROM Guests WHERE RoomNo = ? and AccessKey = ?',[room, accesskey], function(err, rows){
                connection.release();
                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                if(!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, {message : {active : true, text : 'Incorrect Credentials'}});
                }

                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, rows[0]);
            });
        });
    })
);

//this stretegy is for office user
passport.use(
    'office',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        isOfficeUser = true;
        connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            if(err) {
                winston.log('debug', '------------------------------------ Error: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            connection.query('SELECT idSystemUser, Name, Active, Email, ProfileId, Phone, Password FROM SystemUsers WHERE Email = ?',[email], function(err, rows){
                connection.release();
                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                if(!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, {message : {active : true, text : 'Incorrect Credentials'}});
                }

                //if the user access is revoked
                if(rows[0].Active == 0) {
                    return done(null, false, {message : {active : true, text : 'Your administrator has revoked your access to portal. Please contact your Administrator to get this resolved.'}});
                }

                // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].Password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {message : {active : true, text : 'Incorrect Email or Password'}});
                }
                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, rows[0]);
            });
        });
    })
);
```

However, for some reason I get signed out of my session and it shows the error:

> "failed to deserialize user out of session"

I have to refresh the browser and relogin but then after sometime it logs me off again.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to find another way of passing the status of the user around, because the `isOfficeUser` basically becomes a global that gets overwritten each time _any_ user logs in.

Comment: ok, so can I use something like a app.locals.isOfficeUser? Set it in the app.js as false and then change its status in passport.js?

Comment: No, `app.locals` is also shared. The only "location" that makes sense is the object that represents the user, so `rows[0]`. However, that's an additional complication in that `deserializeUser` will _only_ receive the `id`, which can be either type of user, and from what I can see, a id is not unique between your two tables. So instead of passing just the `id` in `serializeUser`, you need to pass an object that contains both the id and the type of user.

Comment: @robertklep you were absolutly right, instead of just passing the row[0] I am not passing return done(null, {type:'office', user:rows[0]}); -- so a complete obj and I read the type and determine the query and id